# How to set username/password in Firefox when using proxy with auth?

Tags: linux, firefox

Where could I set the username/password if the HTTP/HTTPS proxy requires it?
Is Firefox securely storing the username/password?

Answer (score 2):

Passwords and client SSL certificates are stored in database files like key3.db under your Firefox profile directory.  Those passwords and certificates are secure (not stored as plain-text) if, and only if, you have a master password set in Firefox.  You can set the master password under Preferences -> Security.  Once a master password is set, you will need to enter it the first time Firefox attempt to access the secure store or attempts a SSL connection.  You can also set a timeout, IIRC, for Firefox to forget the master password and it will ask next time it's needed.  Without a master password, there is no way for Firefox to securely store something that only it/the user can see.